# Node.js method invoke

Tags: javascript, node.js, class

I just started new project, and I want to use classes and other stuff from ES6. I don't want to keep all methods in one file with class, so I've got index.js file with class, and one for methods. Is solution like that correct? I mean is there any risk of some issues later?

// index.js (File with class)

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(options) {
        ...
    }

    method(){
        lib.serve.call(this)
    }
}
```

// lib.js (File for methods)

```
function serve() {
    // method code with this = MyClass
}

module.exports = {
    serve: serve
}
```

Comment: You should check out mixins and [extends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends)

Comment: use arrow function and you won't need to use .call(this).

Comment: @teivaz, Can I extend class without changing it's name?

Comment: @MaksymilianTomczyk changing its name? There's no need for that - simply add `extends <what you want>` to declaration (name of the class won't change).

Comment: @teivaz But if I use Class1 extends Class2, then I need to invoke method from Class2. Class2.method(). Is there aby option to make methods from Class2 accessible in Class1? I need to add more than one class to Class1

Comment: @MaksymilianTomczyk What are you really trying to do?

Comment: @teivaz I want to store methods code in other file.

Comment: @MaksymilianTomczyk Then use mixins